# HyperLedger fabric error during the channel creation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've got a problem during the creation of the first channel.I'm using the fabric samples from the tutorial and after a while i got this problem out of blue.I think it's because i let the network with some peer running for a while, while i was away from the computer.
This is the problem i got:

```
2024-03-13 16:19:42.524 CET 0001 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 1.611265ms with error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "tlsca.org1.example.com") remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051
```

I've expected the peer to join the network as always but i dont know why this time something is changed
I've tried: shutting the network down, remove all'images but it dosen't work either.
Maybe some file in the TLS certificate has changed but i dont know how to resolve it.
Any help?